# pop up on status change in case object

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I am new to development field and I am trying to build one pop up alert box in my case object.

When ever my status field is `closed` I want to display pop up.

Can anyone please help me?

```
<apex:page standardController="case">
   <script>
      windows.document.onload = new function(e)
      {

      if({case.JIRA_Status__c= 'Closed'})
      {
      alert("True");
      }
      else
      {
      alert("false";)
      }
      }
   </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: alert("false";) Semi colon is misplaced here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are building this functionality on the VF Page, For that get your Case Status value in VF page by defining the variable with  getter setter property, then use that variable at the page like that

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="case">

<!-- JS Section -->
<script>
 var caseStatus = '{!case.JIRA_Status__c}';

 window.onload = function () {
   if(caseStatus == 'Closed'){
     // case closed write alert here
     alert('Case is closed');
   }
   else{
     // for else case
   }
 }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54498/discussion-on-answer-by-user2809299-pop-up-on-status-change-in-case-object).

Comment: where can i find chat window?

Comment: It is in comment itself above or click on the this link:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54498/discussion-on-answer-by-user2809299-pop-up-on-status-change-in-case-object